# Rendering a twig template in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, twig

I'm trying to render a twig (with twigjs) template within a chrome extension. I'm currently compiling the following typescript with a browserify build script.

```
import * as twig from "twig"

const MAIN_TEMPLATE: string = chrome.runtime.getURL("twig/main.html.twig");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        twig.renderFile(MAIN_TEMPLATE, (err: Error, html: string) => {
            document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = html;
        });
});
```

I've made sure to include the files in my `manifest.json`, as such.

```
...
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "twig/*.html.twig"
    ]
...
```

However, upon running this, I get the following stacktrace. I'm not really sure what to do, as the URL that `chrome.runtime.getURL` returns does resolve if I punch it into my address bar.

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.stat is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (twig.js:1)
    at Object.e.Templates.loadRemote (twig.js:1)
    at Object.e.exports.twig (twig.js:1)
    at Object.e.exports.renderFile (twig.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (browser-action.ts:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through some of the `twigjs` source code, it looks like it was a mistake of mine to use the `renderFile` helper. This is more correct.

```
const MAIN_TEMPLATE_URI: string = chrome.runtime.getURL("twig/main.html.twig");
const MAIN_TEMPLATE: twig.Template = twig.twig({href: MAIN_TEMPLATE_URI, async: false};

document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = MAIN_TEMPLATE.render({tabs, tabListTemplate: TAB_LIST_TEMPLATE_URI});
```

I used async false since it's only going to be getting from a local connection, so there really shouldn't be any lag loading the template synchronously.